# Google Analytics for cookie-based A/B testing (same URL for A and B)

Tags: google-analytics, url, cookie, a-b-testing

I have a website with share-friendly URLs like `example.com/register`

I implemented A/B testing as a cookie because I don't want ugly unsharable URLs like `example.com/registerA` and `example.com/registerB`.

What is the best practice to see A/B testing in Google Analytics, even though the URL is the same?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Content Experiments is meant for separate A/B URLs, but it can be hacked to use the same URL, as described in [this article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side).

The general idea is to:

- Use the usual Content Experiments wizard,
- Fill the 2 A/B URL fields with dummy URLs,
- Insert JavaScript code to modify page content on the client side.

*Thanks Eike for the link!*